# "message": "X-CSRF-Token request header is missing"

Tags: 8

When using postman to fire post request I get this message. Does anyone has idea how to disable it? In this case it is post to register user so no authentification is required.

Comment: Disabling the protection represents a security hole so I doubt there's a built-in way to disable it. CSRF is not related to authentication, it's a separate protection measure, so relying on the user being authenticated isn't enough. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/security/writing-secure-code/create-forms-in-a-safe-way-to-avoid-cross-site-request-forgeries for more info

Comment: I put header field X-CSRF-Token with value I got after running get request on my site with sufix /rest/session/token

Answer (score 5):

One reason you may get an `X-CSRF-Token request header is missing` when testing with Postman is that you are using bearer authentication but you also have a session cookie.

Postman will automatically save session cookies and send them with requests, so if you are trying to debug decoupled registration, you may notice this error.

There is more info in the [drupal.org issue here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3055260).

To fix it, you can be vigilant about deleting the cookies after each request when testing with Postman, or apply the patch in the linked issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is not recommend to remove the X-CSRF-Token. Instead you should get the token from  /rest/session/token and add this token in your header with this value.

But if you want to disable it you can write this below line to your settings.php file  $conf['services_csrf_token_check_disabled'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 8 to create a POST rest api with oauth2, and postman to test it, you can, in postman, create a new tab using GET, and point to the url:

```
https://drupal_localhost/rest/session/token
```

Then send the request and copy the response token to the POST tab in postman, under the Headers:

```
X-CSRF-Token          <previous_token>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah for Drupal 9 ect
you can do the GET "session/token" ect then use the header

but if you think its silly to have to do 2 requests then you could do something like this....

make a Route Subscriber ...

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
//Get the Route name here ..
if ($route = $collection->get('rest.something.POST')) {
   $req = $route->getRequirements();
   unset($req['_csrf_request_header_token']); //<-- this bit
   $route->setRequirements($req);
 }
```

Drupal Docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

and Credit to @Patrick Kenny because yep postman does that so it will work the Frist time but then wont due to the auto cookie nice catch
confusing if using things like the key_auth module.